# jq merge values of same key into an array?

Tags: linux, jq

I have a SQL resultset exported as JSON, in the form of 1:1 mappings in an array.

e.g.

```
[
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "A Level"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "IB"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "University"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "GCSE"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "Mentoring"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "13 Plus"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "11 Plus"
  },
etc.....
```

I would like to coalesce the levels into a single subject key like so:

```
[
   "Accounting": ["A Level", "IB", "University"],
   "Foo": ["Foo Intro", "Foo Basics", "Intermediate Foo"] 
]
```

*Note:* no anonymous objects

How can I achieve this with jq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given

```
$ jq '.' file.json
[
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "A Level"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Foo",
    "level": "IB"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "University"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Foo",
    "level": "GCSE"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "Mentoring"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Accounting",
    "level": "13 Plus"
  },
  {
    "subject": "Foo",
    "level": "11 Plus"
  }
]
```

then borrowing heavily from [Reshape a jq array with summarized data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666772/4440445)

```
$ jq 'reduce .[] as $d (null; .[$d.subject] += [$d.level])' file.json 
{
  "Accounting": [
    "A Level",
    "University",
    "Mentoring",
    "13 Plus"
  ],
  "Foo": [
    "IB",
    "GCSE",
    "11 Plus"
  ]
}
```

*Note: the outer level is an object rather than an array (as in your expected output - which doesn't appear to be valid JSON).*

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how you'd do it with `jq` (I find it easier to write something in a general-purpose language like perl than to learn single-purpose tools like `jq`...if I used json data more often, it would probably be worth my time to learn more than its most basic uses), but it's pretty easy with perl's [JSON](https://metacpan.org/release/JSON) module.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use JSON;

# hash-of-arrays to hold an array of "level"s for each "subject"
my %merged;

# slurp the input into scalar string variable $text
my $text; { local $/; $text=<> }

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $data = $json->decode($text);  # parse json text into $data arrayref

# loop over each row of $data and insert into %merged
foreach my $row (@$data) {
  my $key = $row->{subject};
  my $val = $row->{level};

  push @{ $merged{$key} }, $val;
};

# pretty-print %merged as json
print $json->pretty->encode(\%merged), "\n";
```

sample output:

```
$ ./merge-json.pl input.json 
{
   "Accounting" : [
      "A Level",
      "IB",
      "University",
      "GCSE",
      "Mentoring",
      "13 Plus",
      "11 Plus"
   ],
   "Foo" : [
      "Foo Intro",
      "Foo Basics",
      "Intermediate Foo"
   ]
}
```

If you're running Debian or Ubuntu or similar, you can install the JSON module with `sudo apt-get install libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl` (this should install both the perl native version **and** the faster compiled C version of the module, [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/dist/JSON-XS)).  It's probably packaged for other distros too.  Otherwise, install it with `cpan`.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach from [that of steeldriver's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663928/116858) is to group the data by the `subject` key, then collect all the `level` values as arrays under the respective `subject`.

The following uses the same test data that steeldriver is using:

```bash
$ jq 'group_by(.subject) | map({ (first.subject):  map(.level) }) | add' file
{
  "Accounting": [
    "A Level",
    "University",
    "Mentoring",
    "13 Plus"
  ],
  "Foo": [
    "IB",
    "GCSE",
    "11 Plus"
  ]
}
```

The `add` at the end merges the elements of the array that the preceding `map()` creates.